# Setting keep alive on windows server 2016 throws WSAENOPROTOOPT (10042) error

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, .net-6.0, tcp-keepalive

I am trying to set keep alive times on a connected socket and getting following exception

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10042): An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, Int32 optionValue)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketExtensions.SetKeepAlive(Socket socket, Boolean keepAlive, Int32 keepAliveTime, Int32 keepAliveInterval, Int32 keepAliveRetryCount)
   at ServerService.Service.OnManagerConnection(IConnection sender, Socket socket)
```

This is the code that is being called

```
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveTime, 1);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveInterval, 1);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveRetryCount, 5);
```

The exception is only thrown on Windows Server 2016, same code works on other Windows versions and linux.

Hope someone can shed some light where the problem could be.

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: Its SocketOptionName.TcpKeepAliveRetryCount, hmm will check the doc, been using native win apis before we switched to the net6 apis. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of these options are not supported before Windows 1709, namely `TcpKeepAliveTime` and `TcpKeepAliveInterval`. And `TcpKeepAliveRetryCount` is only available beginning 1703. Windows Server 2016 is equivalent to Windows 10 version 1607.

[The Winsock documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-tcp-socket-options#windows-support-for-ipproto_tcp-options) says under the `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` options:

> "This option is available starting with Windows 10, version 1709."

And for `TCP_KEEPCNT` it says:

> Starting with Windows 10, version 1703

You will therefore just have to use a `try` `catch` as there appears to be no way to check supported options.